# how to use subdirectories in the url-key

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, url-key

I need to save a subdirectory within the url-key for products and categories but the rewrite rule from Magento still converts the "/" into a "-".

Has anyone a idea to solve this "problem"?

Answer (score 1):

The subdirectories are created automatically by the order of your category tree.  You do not put subdirectories in the url key at the product configuration in admin.

If you are wanting to show the full category path, including subdirectories in your product urls, you need to go to system > configuration > catalog > catalog > Search Engine Optimizations and set Use Categories Path for Product URLs to YES.  Then reindex all indexes and flush cache.

Comment: True. But there may be cases where you do need slashes in your product's url key, but you cannot create appropriate categories. So an answer which solves the real issue would be interesting.

Comment: I see your point, but seems complicated since slashes communicate directories to the browser.  Maybe something like this would work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables - but doubtful magento admin will accept escapes

Comment: Yeah, Magento escapes `%2F` to `-2f` by default.

Comment: I found a extension which will do what I need for my project:
[link](http://extensions.activo.com/url-seo-pro-for-magento.html)

Comment: Interesting. Good luck with that. To me that sounds like some potential future stress if this is a long term project.

Answer (score 0):

I forked an extension for doing this with the categories... With some coding skills you can do the same for the products!
https://github.com/fullbl/snh_settings_CategoryParentUrl